# How many collaborators can I add to a public/private github repo? Can I prevent collaborators from merging pull requests?

Tags: github, version-control, open-source

I have 2 questions:

1. How many collaborators can I add to a public/private github repo?
2. Can I prevent collaborators from merging pull requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can have an unlimited amount of contributors on public and private repositories.
2. I don't think you can prevent contributors from merging PRs.

Comment: But why did I find some old answers that say that I'm limited to 3 collaborators? Was this an old restriction that was removed?

Comment: It probably was an old restriction I have only been on GitHub for a few months. Look at the details here: https://github.com/settings/billing/plans